# How to plot the x-axis of a pandas bar plot in numerical order rather than based on y-axis value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas df that looks something like this

```
,Difference Max
0,12.0
1,1.0
2,-7.0
3,-5.0
4,2.0
5,3.0
6,10.0
7,0.0
8,0.0
9,3.0
10,3.0
```

from this df I would like to plot a bar chart/histogram showing the number of occurrences for each value in the 'Difference Max' column. I currently have this bar plot
[image]

using the following code:

```
df_maxdif['Difference Max'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
```

but I would like to have the x-axis in numerical order from -21 on the leftmost side up to 10 on the rightmost side. I've tried simply plotting kind = 'hist' but its not quite what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chain `value_counts()` with `sort_index`:

```
df_maxdif['Difference Max'].value_counts().sort_index().plot(kind='bar')
```

Or use `plt.hist`:

```
plt.hist(df['Difference Max'], bins=np.arange(-21,10))
```

Output (for `plt.hist`):

[image]

Comment: Clutch. thank you. I knew it had to be something simple. I just was not looking in the right places.